# Process.Start fails for .docx files only with "WinRT information: An item cannot be found with the specified name"

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, desktop-bridge

I am using WPF app packaged for the Store with `<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />`
and this was working until recently

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"c:\test\test.docx";
proc.Start();
```

but now it fails with

```
WinRT information: An item cannot be found with the specified name
```

and it only fails with Office documents, while any other file type I have tested works. When I run non-packaged version of the same exe it works without issues. What is happening here and is there a workaround?

EDIT:
[image: Code and error]

It is the simplest possible code as seen in screenshot: Windows Application Packaging Project with Process Start. Windows account is Microsoft Live Account with Admin privileges on local machine.
Ran with Build>Deploy Solution, and started from Start menu.
It is very inconsistent. I am uploading so long after original post as it started working when I wanted to reply, and now again it is not working without modifying.

It is a 3 minute code but I have packaged it here:
[WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7290acc1ed5506d82f64e3155036e43e20210414161911/3d8b5489594ae2f1a2a2a222fefaa09120210414161938/8985c0)

Comment: Are the files that you are trying to open part of the MSIX package or they are loaded from a folder outside the package, exactly as mentioned in your sample?

Comment: @BogdanMitrache these are regular files on disk

Comment: I have tested your code by creating a WPF app and packaging the app with a **Windows Application Packaging Project**. The code could work to open a .docx file in the WPF app and in the packaged app. Could you please share us more detailed code about the `proc`? It is better if you could provide us with a minimal sample by using OneDrive or GitHub.

Comment: @YanGu yes, I am using Windows Application Packaging Project. Please see new edit with code and screenshot of VS, File,error message and additional details.